# scala slick query return value

Tags: scala, slick

I am rather new at Scala and have been struggling with slick and can't see how to return the results of a query to the calling method

I have a simple UserDto

```
case class UserDto(val firstName:String,
  val lastName:String,
  val userName:String,
  val isAdmin:Boolean) {}
```

a User table object

```
object User extends Table[(String, String, String, Boolean)]("USER") {

  def firstName = column[String]("FIRST_NAME")
  def lastName = column[String]("LAST_NAME")
  def userName = column[String]("USER_NAME")
  def admin = column[Boolean]("IS_ADMIN")

  def * = firstName ~ lastName ~ userName ~ admin

}
```

and a query class

```
class UserQuerySlickImpl(dataSource:DataSource) {

  def getResults(userName:String):Option[UserDto] = {
    var resultDto:Option[UserDto] = None

    Database.forDataSource(dataSource) withSession {
      val q = for {u <- User if u.userName is userName}
      yield (u.firstName, u.lastName, u.userName, u.admin)

      for (t <- q) {
        t match {
          case (f:String, l:String, u:String, a:Boolean) => 
            resultDto = Some(new UserDto(f, l, u, a))
        }
      }
    }
    resultDto
  }
}
```

I can query the database and get the user that matches the username, but the only way I could figure out how to return that user is by creating a var outside of the `Database.forDataSource....{}`.

Is there a better way that does not use the var but returns the `resultDto` directly.

also is there a way to construct the `UserDto` directly from the first for comprehension rather than needing the second for (t <- q) ...

I am using  slick_2.10.0-M7, version 0.11.1.

Comment: Have a look at this example: https://github.com/slick/slick-examples/blob/master/src/main/scala/scala/slick/examples/lifted/MultiDBCakeExample.scala

Answer (score 9):

Your `q` is a query, not a list of results. The presence of `foreach` might be a little confusing in that respect, but to obtain a `List` of results, you need to do `q.list` first. That gives you methods like `map` and `foldLeft` and so on.

If you want to get a single/the first result in an `Option`, use `q.firstOption`. Once you have that, you can `map` your function over the resulting 'Option[(...)]` to transform the tuple into the desired DTO.

An alternative way would be to specify a custom mapping that automatically maps your result tuples to some case class by using the `<>` operator, see http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/0.11.2/lifted-embedding.html#tables:

```
case class User(id: Option[Int], first: String, last: String) 

object Users extends Table[User]("users") {
  def id = column[Int]("id", O.PrimaryKey, O.AutoInc)
  def first = column[String]("first")
  def last = column[String]("last")
  def * = id.? ~ first ~ last <> (User, User.unapply _)
}
```

Comment: +1 Great answer - Where did you find this documented, ie. first, firstOption, etc? I could not locate it in the Scala Doc or anywhere else.

Comment: Thanks. :) The documentation is a bit of a patchwork thing for me. I cobble stuff together from looking at the docs I linked, the mailing list, StackOverflow and https://github.com/slick/slick-examples. The `firstOption` came from poking around in the source code. Looking at ScalaQuery stuff (e.g. projects on GitHub that use it) helps too. And then there's [this ebook by Adam Mackler](https://mackler.org/LearningSlick) which looks quite useful.

Answer (score 8):

I haven't toyed with Slick yet but if it's reasonable (by which I mean consistent with Scala conventions) you should be able to do something like

```
def getResults(userName:String):Option[UserDto] =
  Database.forDataSource(dataSource) withSession {
    val q = for {u <- User if u.userName is userName}
      yield (u.firstName, u.lastName, u.userName, u.admin)

    q.firstOption map { case (f, l, u, a) => UserDto(f, l, u, a) }
  }
```

This is exactly what you would do if `q` was a `List[(String, String, String, Boolean)]`.

Cleaning this up a bit, you can write

```
def getResults(userName:String):Option[UserDto] =
  Database.forDataSource(dataSource) withSession {
    (for (u <- User if u.userName is userName)
      yield UserDto(u.firstName, u.lastName, u.userName, u.admin)).firstOption
  }
```

Otherwise, you should be able to use

```
q foreach { 
   case (f, l, u, a) => return Some(UserDto(f, l, u, a))
}
return None
```

Generally, `return` statements like this one should be avoided, so hopefully `q`'s type gives you something more functional to work with.

Comment: thanks for such a quick response, As it turns out, the val q does not have a head or headOption method but does support a foreach.  This means that I can replace the 2nd for comprehension with q foreach { case (....) => resultDto = Some(UserDto( ... )    This is cleaner and answers the second question very nicely

Comment: I'm still not clear on how to get the resultDto out of the first Database.forDataSource(dataSource) withSession { ... } block without having to resort to an external var that is updated within the block

Comment: The `withSession` method takes a function parameter and returns the result of calling that function, so all you need to do is ensure that the value of the `withSession` block (i.e., the value of the last expression in the block) is the Option[UserDto] that you want to return. I'll clarify the code in my answer.

Comment: Hat tip to @eriksensei for `firstOption` rather than `headOption`, although I haven't checked the API to verify.

Comment: that `Some` was key!